# How to allow space in numeric regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate 'int' field with javascript regular expression.

I am using this RE string

```
var numbers =/^[0-9]+$/;
```

This expresion does not allow spaces in the text box.

How do I create a regular expression which allows for spaces in the text box?

Comment: What do you mean by "allows for spaces"? The answers so far demonstrate that this can be interpreted in several (incompatible) ways.

Answer (score 5):

Add optional spaces with:

```
var numbers =/^\s*[0-9]+\s*$/;
```

Comment: Although the other answer `/^[0-9 ]+$/` more directly answers the question, I feel like this is what they *actually* want.

Comment: This allows spaces at either end, but not scattered within the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Add a space to the character set:

```
/^[0-9 ]+$/
```

If you want to guarantee that at least one digit exists, you could use a lookahead:

```
/^(?=\s*\d)[\d\s]+$/
```

Comment: That will allow input of only spaces.

Comment: @ blender: code error by this expression string, it shows Invalid argument error..

Comment: @user2110346: What browser are you using?

Comment: @ blender: again invalid argument error by this expression /^(?=\s*\d)[\d\s]+$/

Comment: @user2110346: I can't blindly debug things. You have to at least post the code and the browser that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This regex allow the numbers and spaces.

```
 /[^\d\s]/
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you want to allow spaces and whether you want input of spaces only (no digits) to be allowed. If you want to require at least one digit and any distribution of spaces, you can do this:

```
/^(\s*\d+)+\s*$/
```

This will allow input such as " 202 555 1212 "

Comment: @ Ted Hopp: no i dont want output like this, i just want only numbers and if user does not enter anything then it should allow to go

Comment: @user2110346 - Perhaps you should edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish. A few examples would also help. The answers so far represent (at least) three different interpretations of your requirements and you seem to like none of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will permit to use spaces, tabs and digits, but require to use at least one digit:

```
^\s*\d[\d\s]*$
```

[Online fiddle.re demo](http://fiddle.re/3tme6).

Comment: which browser you are using? it works for everything I tried. [fiddle.re demo](http://fiddle.re/3tme6) also validates.